Using langchain with Azure Document Intelligence - no module 'azure'
Just trying to run the demo code from langchain:
file_path = "TEST_EN.pptx"
endpoint = "my endpoint"
key = "my key"
analysis_features = ["ocrHighResolution"]
loader = AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader(
    api_endpoint=endpoint,
    api_key=key,
    file_path=file_path,
    api_model="prebuilt-layout",
    analysis_features=analysis_features,
    #mode="page",
)

Gives me No module named 'azure'.
I have installed:
azure-ai-formrecognizer
azure-ai-documentintelligence and even azure-core


I guess my virtual environment was invalid. Started from scratch and it seems to work

Can you add more information in your answer so this can help others?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
